# Repeat storyboard transitions definite number of times

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, animation, windows-phone-8

I am trying to implement an opacity transition to a `Button` and `TextBlock` element in Windows Phone 8.

These are the `Button` and `TextBlock` element I'm transitioning:

```
<Button
                x:Name="letterHole" 
                Width="230"
                Height="387"
                Opacity="0"
                BorderThickness="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Click="letterHole_Click">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Main/letterHoleBackground@2x.png"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <TextBlock
                Name="letter"
                Text=""
                FontSize="60"
                TextAlignment="Center"
                Foreground="Blue"
                Margin="378,268,376,109"/>
```

The `Button` has a background image and the `TextBlock` is positioned on top of it.

These are the Storyboard transitions I'm using:

```
        <Storyboard x:Name="fadeInAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="letterHole"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="wait">
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="letterHole"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                From="1.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:2"/>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="fadeOutAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="letterHole"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
        </Storyboard>
```

I run them in the following order: `fadeInAnimation`, `wait`, `fadeOutAnimation`, the result being that the element fades in, waits 2 seconds and then fades out.

I'd like to have this animation sequence repeated definite number of times, - right now 6 - and every time it's repeated change the `TextBlock`'s `Text` property.

This is the C# code I'm using:

```
    public ConstructorOfClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string[] letters = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
        int i = 0;
        int show = 6;
        animate();
    }

    private void animate()
    {
        if(show > 0)
        {
            fadeInAnimation.Begin();
            fadeInAnimation.Completed += fadeInAnimation_Completed;
        }
    }

    private void fadeInAnimation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        letter.Text = letters[i];

        wait.Begin();
        wait.Completed += wait_Completed;
    }

    private void wait_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fadeOutAnimation.Begin();

        fadeOutAnimation.Completed +=fadeOutAnimation_Completed;
    }

    private void fadeOutAnimation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        show--;
        i++;
        animate();
    }
```

I've added some variables:

`int show` - number of repetions

`int i` - index of the `letters[]` array

At every repetion a new letter has to be shown.

**The problem** with this is that `i` and `show` don't increment the way I planned it, so after 2-3 repetions `show` gets down to 0.

Also, after trying to debug the problem I've noticed that in the method `fadeOutAnimation_Completed()` sometimes the `animate()` method isn't getting called, resulting that for some reason `i` and `show` gets incremented 2 or 3 times again.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time `wait` is completed you do

```
fadeOutAnimation.Completed += fadeOutAnimation_Completed;
```

which means that `fadeOutAnimation_Completed` will be called once during 1st run, twice during 2nd run and 3 times during 3rd run so if you start with `show = 6` after 1st run it will be 5, 2nd run 3 and 3rd will be 0. I think that what you do in 3 storyboards you can do in 2 if you use `BeginTime` on the second one:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="fadeInAnimation" Completed="fadeInAnimation_Completed">
    <DoubleAnimation 
        From="0" 
        To="1" 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
        Storyboard.TargetName="letterHole" 
        Duration="0:0:1"/>                
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Name="fadeOutAnimation" Completed="fadeOutAnimation_Completed">
    <DoubleAnimation 
        From="1" 
        To="0" 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
        Storyboard.TargetName="letterHole" 
        Duration="0:0:1" 
        BeginTime="0:0:3"/>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: Thanks, this did it. I'm changint the `TextBlock`'s text every time the `Button` element fades in. When using the suggested method for transitioning, how can I see that the fade in sequence is completed?

Comment: I did not notice that you change text after fade in. I've updated my answer. In this case you'll need to use at least 2 `StoryBoards` as completed event fires only at the end of the whole `StoryBoard` but you still should be able to remove `wait` animation if you use `BeginTime`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you subscribe to the `Completed` event of the `Storyboards` multiple times (each time a `Completed` event executes, you resubscribe to the `Completed` event of the next storyboard, which means that next time it executes it one more time).

You should simply subscribe to the Completed events from the XAML:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="fadeInAnimation" Completed="fadeInAnimation_Completed">
    <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="letterHole"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
        From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Name="wait" Completed="wait_Completed">
    <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="letterHole"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
        From="1.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:2"/>
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Name="fadeOutAnimation" Completed="fadeOutAnimation_Completed">
    <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="letterHole"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
        From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
</Storyboard>
```

And then in your code-behind (I just removed the event subscriptions):

```
private void animate()
{
    if (show > 0)
    {
        fadeInAnimation.Begin();
    }
}

private void fadeInAnimation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    letter.Text = letters[i];
    wait.Begin();
}

private void wait_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fadeOutAnimation.Begin();
}

private void fadeOutAnimation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    show--;
    i++;
    animate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer too! This seems more cleaner than with adding the events in c#.